# How to save an Int8Array to local file with java

Tags: java

I am trying to save a file on server disk using javascript (frontend) and java (backend).

**Javascript:**

In javascript I have a function that chunk the file and send it to java via ajax.

```js
var reader, file, slice_size = (1024**2)*5;
  
  $(document).on("click", "#dbi-file-upload-submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    file = $("#dbi-file-upload")[0].files[0];
    reader = new FileReader();
    
    submit_file(0);
  });
  
  function submit_file(start){
    let next_slice = start+slice_size;
    let blob = file.slice(start, next_slice);

    reader.onload = function(event){
      let unit8 = new Int8Array(event.target.result);
      console.log(unit8)
      save_slice(unit8).done(function(res){
        let size_done = start + slice_size;
        let percent_done = Math.floor((size_done/file.size)*100);
        
        if(next_slice < file.size){
          $('#dbi-upload-progress').html(`Uploading File -  ${percent_done}%`);
          submit_file(next_slice);
        }else{
          $('#dbi-upload-progress').html(`Done !`);
        }
      });
      
    }
  
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  }
  
  function save_slice(slice){
    var form = new FormData();

    form.append("binary", slice);

    return $.ajax({
      url: '/Save.tstVideo',
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false, 
      data: form
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="dbi-file-upload" type="file"/><br><br>
  <span id="dbi-upload-progress"></span>
  <input id="dbi-file-upload-submit" class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

This is the first time that I program in Java so if you have any suggestions let me know.

I'm trying to make a function in Java that saves the sent chunks from ajax in a txt. When javascript detects the last chunk I want to decode the txt into file with java.

This is how I'm trying to save binary in a txt:

```
import java.io.*;


public class fileToDisk extends Function{   
    @Parameters("binary")
    
    public boolean fileToDisk(String binary){
      
      File file = new File("/userdata/videosmedia/test.txt");

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos)) {
      dos.writeBytes(binary);
      //System.out.println("Successfully written data to the file");
      return true;
    }catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
    
    }
}
```

I tried to do it using base64 but the encoded videos could not be played and someone suggest me to use binary instead of base64.

Comment: What Framework are you using? Something apparently provides the @Parameters("binary") annotation...

Comment: What is your `dos` variable you're acessing in your try-with-resources? ANd why do you open a FileOutputStream you never actuall use?

Comment: If you're uploading a binary file, you probably don't want to output it as a text file.

Comment: @JohannesH. I use a ebdml framework.

Comment: @NomadMaker I was trying to reproduce something I saw on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `base64`, `String` would be the proper type, for binary, a `byte[]` would be what I expect.

Also, since Java 7 the much more convenient `java.nio.file.Files` class is available, which has a even more convenient [write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) method.

In your case, you'd just append the received `byte[]` to a given file (using  `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` and `StandardOpenOption.APPEND`). If you want to mark uncompleted files in some way, you could name them `filename.filetype.chunks` and then send another variable in the final request from the frontend (e.g. `lastChunk = true`) and then rename the file accordingly.

I'd highly discourage to use the `*.txt` file extension for files which are not `*.txt` files. Always keep the proper extension.

This algorithm however only applies for sequential calls from the frontend.